# AngularJS, where to put global lists etc

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJs and have tried to follow many different tutorials. It seems as if there's many ways to code and structure projects in AngularJS.

My goal so far is to create a simple web-site, with login and logout features, and a way to add cars to one portfolios.

My structure is so far:

```
index.html
templates/login.html
templates/dashboard.html
templates/car.html (empty for now)
templates/portfolio.html (empty for now)
js/app.js
js/controllers.js
js/services.js
```

My issue for now is where should I put my user information including my portfolios and where to add and remove cars to the portfolios?
Also, I've got an entire list of cars which I would like to be able to query and show.

I've read that services should work for this, but...

Are there any tutorials online for such a "simple" site, covering the basics of creating portfolios, adding items to them etc.?

I've got my files, if anyone wants to see them, but where should I upload them if so?

Comment: A well respected styleguide is Johnpapa's, [link here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md), it also has rules about folder structure

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a better understanding of different angular components. For example controller is a place you would have your event handling function ($scope functions).
Service, on the other hand, can be used to store the application wide data, in your case login and logout features can be incorporated in services.

All your data (I mean real data, as in what is kept in databases) should be queried using $http services and its method. In case you wish to keep some data on front end itself, then you should keep them in services (or may be return as an object from a factory). If its all static data,a better idea can be to make a constant component (read about angular constants).

May be [this](http://xposeideas.blogspot.com/2015/08/angularjs-application-beginners-guide.html) helps you to start with in case you are really starting with Angular

Answer to your last question: If you wish to share some code for review by users here, you might want to create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) or a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and share the link.

Answer (score 0):

Writing an Application from start is Not Joyful thing while Beginning.

I have a Suggestion for You i.e Choose `MEANJS` Which is the Combination of `MongoDB`,`Nodejs`,`Angularjs` With `ExpressJs`. It has a Project Structure well defined. You can take it as Reference for Future Apps.

Meanjs itself has a sample app working when you installed as per the instructions

[MEANJS with Default Application - Clone with Git,node&npm install,bower install,grunt it Magic -- Local server starts Running with Sample App](http://meanjs.org/)

I Hope this thing helps you :-)